# Where does the index in the while loop change in this PHP snippet?

Tags: php

PHP lists this example as a way to retrieve database data.

```
<?php
$return = []
$qry = "SELECT * FROM exp_member_data";
$res = mysql_query($mem_qry);

function mysql_fetch_all($res) {
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
       $return[] = $row;
   }
   return $return;
}
?>
```

I am confused about how this while loop progresses. What guarantees that `$row=mysql_fetch_array($res)` is different for every iteration of the while loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php):

> ... moves the internal data pointer ahead.

So it doesn't guarantee that it will be *different*, only that it will retrieve the next row.

Comment: Oh ok, so PHP abstracts moving the pointer ahead within its implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A look in php.net helps:

```
Description:
  array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )

Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `mysql_fetch_array` exactly, but typically when you see a pattern like this it's because the fetch function has a side effect of advancing a cursor through an iterable. At the end of the iterable, `mysql_fetch_array` will return a value that evaluates to `false`, and the loop will terminate.

The value of the expression `$a = $b` is the value of `$b`, which is why it works to put the assignment of `$row` in the while condition.